# Javascript scope issue with objects (this)

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var tradingInterface = function() {

    this.json = '';

    this.init = function() {

        $.get( '/whatever',{}, function(data) {
            this.json = data;
            // Rebuilds Everything
            this.rebuildAll();
        });
    };

    this.rebuildAll = function() {
        //whatever here
    };

};
```

Why am I getting in init function the following error?

```
ReferenceError: this.rebuildAll is not defined
this.rebuildAll();
```

Why can I access to this.json without scoping problems but not to this.rebuildAll?

I wrote a similar previous thread but i was redirected to [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) but i am not able to make it work properly.

As thw thread suggets, I tried with:

```
var tradingInterface = function() {

    this.json = '';
    var self = this;
    this.init = function() {

        $.get( '/whatever',{}, function(data) {
            this.json = data;
            // Rebuilds Everything
            self.rebuildAll();
        });
    };

    this.rebuildAll = function() {
        //whatever here
    };

};
```

The error disappears but rebuildAll function is not doing what it should...

I need some help...

Regards,

Comment: *"Why can I access to this.json without scoping problems but not to this.rebuildAll?"* You are **assigning** to `this.json`. You can always assign a property to an object (almost always). However, you are **reading** `this.rebuildAll` and try to call it as a function. Since `this.rebuildAll` is `undefined`, you cannot call it. *Assigning* to `this.rebuildAll` would work fine as well (although of course it wouldn't what you wanted to do): `this.rebuildAll = 42;`.

Comment: Are you serious man? I wrote in my thread that I already read that thread and that did not help me, read what i wrote first and don't finish in the header...

Comment: You are getting the error because `this` in the function references to the `window` object and it does not have the `rebuildAll` method.

Comment: @Egidi Felix Kling's post answers your question.

Comment: Yes, Felix is correct.  Your scope for `this` inside of the `$.get....` isn't actually `tradingInterface`.  To clear things up, make `this.json = 'test'` and then `console.log(this.json)` inside your `$.get`

Comment: The fact that you only replaced `this.rebuildAll` with `self.rebuildAll`, but not `this.json`, suggests me that you haven't fully understood the explanation and solution in the linked question. I'd suggest you read through it again, but I'm also happy to get feedback how to make the answer easier to understand (I wrote the linked question/answer).

Comment: Working demo.  `this.json` does need to be `self.json`: http://jsbin.com/jujelekimo/1/edit?js,output (click "Run with JS")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The error disappears but rebuildAll function is not doing what it should...

You are not explaining what the `rebuildAll` is supposed to do, so I can only assume that the issue is that you didn't replace

```
this.json = data;
```

with

```
self.json = data;
```

Inside the the `$.get` callback, `this` refers to a different object than `self`. This is all explained in the [question/answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

---

> Why can I access to this.json without scoping problems but not to this.rebuildAll?

You are **assigning** to `this.json`. You can (almost) always assign a property to an object. However, you are **reading** `this.rebuildAll` and try to call it as a function. Since `this.rebuildAll` is `undefined`, you cannot call it.

Simplified example:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 42; // works, foo didn't exist before
obj.bar = function() {}; // works, bar didn't exist before

obj.bar(); // works because bar exists
obj.baz(); // doesn't work, because baz doesn't exist
```